# How can I call a BigQuery procedure from the bq command-line tools?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, call, procedure, invoke

How can I invoke a BigQuery procedure from the bq command-line tools?
I tried with the following forms, but it didn't work for me:

```
bq query 'call dataset.procedure();'
bq query 'call `project.dataset.procedure`();'
```

Is it true that the `call` keyword is not yet supported by the `bq` command-line client? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use #standardSQL:

```
bq query "call temp.proc()"
```

Gives the error:

> Error in query string: Error processing job 'fh:bqjob_r40': Encountered "  "call "" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting:
>   
>   [Try using standard SQL (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql)]

Follow that link, and you'll see that one way to fix this is:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false "call temp.proc()"
```